# How to use IPSec / Openswan with Amazon's Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) and EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ipsec, vpc, amazon-vpc

Does anyone know how to use Openswan to create an IPSec tunnel to a Cisco router on EC2?

I keep reading that people can or they cannot set up the IPSec tunnels on Amazon's cloud. Is it possible or not?

If so, can someone point me to a tutorial where it was successful?

Answer (score 9):

### Update

AWS has just dropped the requirement to establish [Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x304.html) peerings in order to use the built in VPN connectivity to an [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/11/11/connecting-to-amazon-vpc/), see [Amazon VPC - Additional VPN Features](http://openfoo.org/blog/amazon_vpc_with_linux.html):

> You can now create Hardware VPN connections to your VPC using static
>   routing. This means that you can **establish connectivity using VPN
>   devices that do not support BGP** such as Cisco ASA and **Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2008 R2**. You can also use  **Linux** to establish a
>   Hardware VPN connection to your VPC. **In fact, any IPSec VPN
>   implementation should work**. *[emphasis mine]*

The outlined reason for this change specifically highlights BGP as a previous barrier to adoption of this otherwise very appealing VPN connectivity to a VPC:

> First, BGP can be difficult to set up and to manage, [...]. Second, some firewalls and entry-level
>   routers support IPSec but not BGP. These devices are very popular in
>   corporate branch offices. As I mentioned above, this change
>   dramatically increases the number of VPN devices that can be used to
>   connect to a VPC. [...]

I couldn't agree more - accordingly you should now be able to facilitate Openswan (or the built in Linux IPSec stack) to connect to the respective built in VPC IPSec functionality.

---

### Initial Answer

A related tutorial based on [Racoon](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x304.html) is available at [Amazon VPC with Linux](http://openfoo.org/blog/amazon_vpc_with_linux.html). **However**, before you dive into that, I highly recommend to read the referring article [Connecting to Amazon VPC](http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/11/11/connecting-to-amazon-vpc/) first, at least section *Using Linux as VPN Server*:

> Let us say you have decided to use some linux for your VPN server. For
>   an IPSec newbie there is no obvious reason that this is a bad idea.
>   And because one soon finds a tutorial like
>   http://openfoo.org/blog/amazon_vpc_with_linux.html it seems possible
>   to perform that task. Following this tutorial you should be able to
>   ping the two BGP servers from your VPN server. [...] But after that point you will
>   start to get in trouble. Maybe you are able to connect to a server in
>   your VPC. But there is one thing you won’t get working stable:
>   Connecting from the VPC to some server in your home net
>   192.168.1.1/24. That is because linux has a policy-based IPSec implementation. [...]

Consequently the author concludes:

> And the last and most important reason is that **Openswan is not
>   intended to be used that way**. Abusing software in a security relevant
>   place doesn’t seem to be a good idea. *[emphasis mine]*

YMMV as usual, but you have been warned ;)