# openvpn software client and Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to use the openvpn software client directly with the default amazon VPC gateway?  I've seen articles regarding doing it with an OpenVPN Access server, but I was wondering if it someone has figured out how to connect an openvpn software client directly to the VPC gateway, since really its just a VPN access server.

If this is possible, could you please point me to a tutorial or provide some guidance?  My Google-Fu keeps turning up OpenVPN AS articles.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their documentation, http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/, Amazon states that they use IPSec to encrypt the communication, OpenVPN uses SSL/TLS to do it, therefore I see no way to connect the two.

Comment: is there an IPSec equivalent(s) to the openvpn software client?

Comment: Linux supports IPsec natively, as it is part of its network stack. Regarding connecting, see http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/ it states it is possible, under `Which customer gateway devices can I use to connect to Amazon VPC?`

Comment: thx.  this SO article does a good job with links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496166/how-to-use-ipsec-openswan-with-amazons-virtual-private-cloud-vpc-and-ec2